# Resizing the textView according to text set

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Income:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/UIAllReportIncome"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:maxWidth="120dp"
                android:text="656565465465555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555"
                android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text=">"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

It sets the value of `textView` upto few digits only. How can i make it "wrap content" So that height of text view changes.
E.g

IT should show now

```
65564546546543
555555555555
555555555555
```

etc

However it currently shows only `655456465465`

Comment: Try `android:singleLine="false"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using  `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`  ? Remove it and it will get fixed

Comment: asking and answering your own questions? hmm, seems pretty fraudlent to me. downvote

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these properties of the textview in the xml file

```
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
     android:lines="3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="151515543423452353452346234635645625634564563456356346346365"/>
```

The above show into multiple lines